# Invoke commands on git-bash.exe from C#

Tags: c#, bash, git

I'm try to start a git-bash from c# and want to redirect the `inputStream` for sending commands to the console window.

I did the same for some actions for cmd.exe but the problem is that the bash.exe is a child process of the git-bash process

```cs
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe";
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\git\workspace";
    try
    {
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = exeProcess.StandardInput)
            {
                if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("echo I want to see this");
                    //sw.Flush() // I tried with and without FLush() no different
                }

                // Keep the Console open to see what happend
                while (true)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(400);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Write it to `stdin` of git bash?

Comment: Are you trying to perform git commands?

Comment: any particular reason you want to invoke the bash command line instead of using a library to use git commands? e.g. https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp

Comment: I have a workflow with more than git commands. CMake, python scripting, shell scripts and also git commands.
In best case I can do the same stuff as current but can do it from code

Comment: Maybe look into CI/CD tooling. This sounds like you are trying to build some kind of custom build server / service? (And having just "inherited" one from former developer: _don't_.)

Comment: I have to do some steps from our CI steps to get some special results. I don't inherited this from somebody I only want to automate my manual steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that worked for me.

```cs
// Use ProcessStartInfo class
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe";
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = workspacePath;
startInfo.Arguments = "-c \"echo 'Hello World!';" +
                           "echo 'This is the next command!'; " +
                           "echo 'the last read keeps to shell open'; " +
                           "read\"";
try
{
   Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
   exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
catch ( Exception e)
{
   Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

The benefit is I can execute the exact same steps in the exact same way. If something break I don't have to check my own setup, libs or dependencys.